# SQL-Query to get the first level child details from a single table based on certain conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

A table in my database holds data as below,

```
                     TBLlocations
 -------------------------------------------------------
 LocationId    LocationName      RegisteredUnder    Type
 --------------------------------------------------------
  LOC100        Location1            0               0
  LOC201        Location2           LOC100           2
  LOC102        Location3           LOC201           1
  LOC302        Location4           LOC201           1
  LOC103        Location5           LOC201           1
  LOC104        Location6           LOC201           1
  LOC105        Location7           LOC104           1
  LOC106        Location8           LOC105           1
  LOC107        Location9           LOC106           1
```

Now i have to select locations from the above table such that my query would return the first level locations i.e; considering the above table my query has to return the locations 
which have their type as '1' and should be the first level child locations with type as '1'. From the above table Locations 3 to 6 are the first level locations, so the query should return the following:

```
---------------
   Location3 
   Location4 
   Location5 
   Location6
```

I tried to join the same table providing a condition for the 'Type'.
This is the query I built:

```
Select Distinct t1.LocationId,t1.LocationName,t1.RegisteredUnder from TBLlocations t1
join TBLlocations t2 on t2.RegisteredUnder!=t1.LocationId
where t1.Type='1' and t2.Type='1'
order by t1.RegisteredUnder
```

The above query returned all the locations under type '1' as shown below:

```
--------------------------------------------------
LocationId     LocationName        RegisteredUnder
--------------------------------------------------
  LOC102        Location3           LOC201 
  LOC302        Location4           LOC201
  LOC103        Location5           LOC201
  LOC104        Location6           LOC201
  LOC105        Location7           LOC104 
  LOC106        Location8           LOC105
  LOC107        Location9           LOC106
```

Hence, I need a query that would return the exact result. The only parameter i can use in the query is the 'Type' and it is '1' always.

PS: I am using SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after question changed

```
Declare @a table (LocationId Varchar(100),   LocationName Varchar(100),     RegisteredUnder Varchar(100),   Type int)
Insert into @a  Values('LOC100','Location1','0',0)
Insert into @a  Values('LOC201','Location2','LOC100',2)
Insert into @a  Values('LOC102','Location3','LOC201',1)
Insert into @a  Values('LOC302','Location4','LOC201',1)
Insert into @a  Values('LOC103','Location5','LOC201',1)
Insert into @a  Values('LOC104','Location6','LOC201',1)
Insert into @a  Values('LOC105','Location7','LOC104',1)
Insert into @a  Values('LOC106','Location8','LOC105',1)
Insert into @a  Values('LOC107','Location9','LOC106',1)
;With CTE as
(
Select 0 as level,* from @a where Type=1
UNION ALL
Select   c.Level+1, a.* from @a a
join CTE c on c.LocationId=a.RegisteredUnder and a.Type=1
)     
Select  c1.* from CTE c1
Left Join CTE c2 on c2.LocationId=c1.LocationId and c2.level>0
where c2.LocationId is NULL
order by LEVEL desc,LocationName
```

The answer before question changed

```
Declare @a table (LocationId Varchar(100),   LocationName Varchar(100),     RegisteredUnder Varchar(100),   Type int)
Insert into @a  Values('LOC100','Location1','0',0)
Insert into @a  Values('LOC201','Location2','LOC100',2)
Insert into @a  Values('LOC102','Location3','LOC201',1)
Insert into @a  Values('LOC302','Location4','LOC201',1)
Insert into @a  Values('LOC103','Location5','LOC201',1)
Insert into @a  Values('LOC104','Location6','LOC201',1)
Insert into @a  Values('LOC105','Location7','LOC104',1)
Insert into @a  Values('LOC106','Location8','LOC105',1)
Insert into @a  Values('LOC107','Location9','LOC106',1)
;With CTE as
(
Select 0 as level,* from @a where RegisteredUnder='LOC201'
UNION ALL
Select   c.Level+1, a.* from @a a
join CTE c on c.RegisteredUnder=a.LocationId
) 
Select DISTINCT * from CTE
where level<2
order by LEVEL desc, LocationName
```

Comment: @bummi... I appreciate your prompt response. An edit has been made to the question so please consider editing your post.